# Memory Leak in C++/C# application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, ant, memory-leaks

I have an application which uses a C++ DLL to communicate with a Canon Camera, methods in this C++ DLL are invoked from a C# application. What I've seen in the application is that when taking photos, the memory increases, of course. After I close the "Image Capture Window" the application still holds the same amount of memory as it did, when all of the images were captured.

Since my application exists of many layers of WPF UserControls, I thought that the "Image Preview UserControl" was unable to get garbage collected because of other controls subscribed to an event fired from this control. After some googling, I decided to implement the `Weak Reference Pattern` on the events.

```
 //Source code found here: http://paulstovell.com/blog/weakevents

 public sealed class WeakEventHandler<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly WeakReference _targetReference;
        private readonly MethodInfo _method;


        public WeakEventHandler(EventHandler<TEventArgs> callback)
        {
            _method = callback.Method;
            _targetReference = new WeakReference(callback.Target, true);
        }

        public void Handler(object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var target = _targetReference.Target;
            if (target != null)
            {
                var callback =
                    (Action<object, TEventArgs>)
                        Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Action<object, TEventArgs>), target, _method, true);
                if (callback != null)
                {
                    callback(sender, eventArgs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, if I forget to unsubscribe some events the GC will collect them anyway. After some more testing, this approach did not work, so I decided to use the [Redgate ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

I took three snapshots:

1. Before taking images
2. After I took 4 images
3. After destruction of the wpf controllers

The result when comparing snapshot 1 and 3:

[image: Piechart]

[image]

As you can see the amount of allocated Unmanaged Memory is the big problem here. My first thought would be that the C++ DLL isn't deallocating the allocated memory when the "Image Capture Window" is closed.

Am I correct that the problem is in the C++ plugin? Can I exclude the C# application? As far as I know, all code written in .NET is managed memory.

**Based upon a comment here is how the image arrives from the C++ plugin to the C# plugin:**

From the C++ plugin there is a callback like this:

```
_resultcallback(img->GetImageInfo().Data, img->GetImageInfo().Width, img->GetImageInfo().Height, img->GetImageInfo().BPP);
```

And the method which receives the image on the C# side:

```
    private void OnResultImageCallback(IntPtr imagePtr, int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel)
    {
        _state = CameraState.InitializedStandby;
        _cbResultData.Width = width;
        _cbResultData.Height = height;
        _cbResultData.BitsPerPixel = bitsPerPixel;

        int memSize = bitsPerPixel * width * height / 8;
        _cbResultData.data = new byte[memSize];
        Marshal.Copy(imagePtr, _cbResultData.data, 0, memSize);
        _deleteAllocatedImageFunction(imagePtr);

        if (ImageCaptured != null)
            ImageCaptured(_cbResultData.data, _cbResultData.Width, _cbResultData.Height, _cbResultData.BitsPerPixel);

        _cbResultData.data = null; 
    }
```

I also have a method to clear the allocated memory in my C++ which takes in a byte-pointer like this:

```
BOOL CanonEDSDKWnd::ClearImageBuffer(BYTE* img) {
    _debug->Write(_T("CanonEDSDKWnd::ClearImageBuffer"));
    delete[] img;
    return TRUE;
}
```

Which is called from the C# code with the `IntPtr` from the callback

_deleteAllocatedImageFunction(imagePtr);

Comment: How does an image arrive to your c# code from the C++ library? How's the invocation of unmanaged methods done? How do you store images on the managed side? etc, etc... It's hard to say anything useful without knowledge concerning the code.

Comment: Please see my edit. I think that it should be the essential parts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the object pointed to by `img` in the callback must somehow be deallocated. You should have a c++ function which does `delete img` and it should be called after you copied the data to the managed storage.

Comment: I have a method like this. Please see my edit. Is this approach wrong?

Comment: Where do you call the aforementioned method in the c# code? it does not seem you have the pointer to img in the c# code.

Comment: @GézaTörök Its called after the `Marshal.Copy`. I've edited the answer, it was previously commented out, so I removed it from the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63754/discussion-between-geza-torok-and-tobias-moe-thorstensen).

Answer (score 1):

I think your callback function should look like the following:

C++ side:

```
_resultcallback(
   img                    // extend the signature
   img->GetImageInfo().Data,
   img->GetImageInfo().Width,
   img->GetImageInfo().Height,
   img->GetImageInfo().BPP
);
```

C# side:

```
private void OnResultImageCallback(IntPtr img, IntPtr imagePtr, int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel)
    {
        _state = CameraState.InitializedStandby;
        _cbResultData.Width = width;
        _cbResultData.Height = height;
        _cbResultData.BitsPerPixel = bitsPerPixel;

        int memSize = bitsPerPixel * width * height / 8;
        _cbResultData.data = new byte[memSize];
        Marshal.Copy(imagePtr, _cbResultData.data, 0, memSize);
        _deleteAllocatedImageFunction(img);

        if (ImageCaptured != null)
            ImageCaptured(_cbResultData.data, _cbResultData.Width, _cbResultData.Height, _cbResultData.BitsPerPixel);

        _cbResultData.data = null; 
    }
```

Comment: I dont think this will work, since the `img` is a `unique_ptr`